# HeidiSQL import csv empty fields

Tags: mysql, csv, null, heidisql

I want to import a csv file to my MySQL database with HeidiSQL.

But some of my fields are empty.

What could I do to let HeidiSQL know these empty values have to be seen as NULL-values?

Sample of csv-file (last 2 fields not yet known):

```
    NULL;Students Corner;437452182;;
```

Create commands:

```
    CREATE  TABLE `db`.`customers` (
         `company_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
         `company_name` VARCHAR(40) NULL ,
         `company_number` INT NULL ,
         `company_vat` INT NULL ,
         `company_zip` INT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`company_id`) );
```

I get these error:

```
    Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'company_id' at row 1 */
    Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'company_vat' at row 1 */
    Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'company_zip' at row 1 */
    etc
```

Comment: Post SHOW CREATE TABLE and sample lines from CSV

Comment: You could do it using LOAD DATA INFILE command with SET clause - replace empty strings with NULL values.

Comment: Replace ;; by ;NULL; in your CSV and try again.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If solved it by writing \N in each empty field instead of writing NULL !

Comment: that's good. don't forget to accept your answer if its the one you used. I'd still say the `LOAD DATA INFILE` query solution is better, because one doesn't alwawys have the option to pre-process a CSV file before importing it. Writing the query allows you to put all of that logic into a single script, which means next time you can just run it as a single command, and not worry about checking the contents of the file.

Comment: Wow, this answer is a total lifesaver! I've been trying to import a huge CSV file (200k rows and 34 columns), and it has been driving me crazy for throwing me errors and warnings about NULL values. It seems that using `\N` in place of `NULL` or just a blank field worked magic! :)

Comment: the `Fields Escaped By` character must be \ in Heidi to recognize that syntax.

Answer (score 5):

You can import CSV files into MySQL using a `LOAD DATA INFILE` query.

In your case, you would write something like this:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE filename.txt
INTO TABLE customers
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(@id, @name, @number, @vat, @zip)
SET
  company_id     = (CASE WHEN @id='' THEN NULL ELSE @id END),
  company_name   = (CASE WHEN @name='' THEN NULL ELSE @name END),
  company_number = (CASE WHEN @number='' THEN NULL ELSE @number END),
  company_vat    = (CASE WHEN @vat='' THEN NULL ELSE @vat END),
  company_zip    = (CASE WHEN @zip='' THEN NULL ELSE @zip END)
```

(you may need to adjust this, depending on your end of line markers, etc, but this should be pretty close to what you need)